# ways to view a webcam in linux through commandline

Tags: webcam

Can someone advise the different options available to view a webcam in linux through command line?

The only way I know is like this :

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=640:height=480:device=/dev/video0 -fps 15
```

If you know other command line tools,please tell me.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)

Comment: one more that's not listed there is  : gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink